# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array with metadata and records

Tags: c#, json, json.net, metadata, json-deserialization

Here is a sample of the JSON data I am getting back from a web service.

It has a single node of "odata.metadata", another single node of "value", and then the repeating records consisting of 3 fields "Code", "Name" and "XTag". This is in a string variable called **Content**

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://notthereal.domain:3148/system/OData/$metadata#pageLocationList","value":[{"Code":"LOC-A","Name":"Location A","XTag":"36;DgAAAAJ7/zEAMAAwAC0ATQBBAEkATgAAAAAA8;264943250;"},{"Code":"LOC-B","Name":"Location B","XTag":"36;DgAAAAJ7/zEAMAAxAC0ATQBBAEkATgAAAAAA8;388906690;"},{"Code":"LOC-C","Name":"Location C","XTag":"36;DgAAAAJ7/zEAMAAyAC0ATQBBAEkATgAAAAAA8;388844480;"},{"Code":"LOC-D","Name":"Location D","XTag":"36;DgAAAAJ7/zEAMAAzAC0ATQBBAEkATgAAAAAA8;388876720;"}]}
```

I have the following as the model, which I got by pasting the JSON data into the class.

```
public class ModelPageLocationList
{
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string XTag { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the code trying to deserialise it...

```
DataPageLocationList = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelPageLocationList>>(content);
```

..and this is the error message. I am stuck! Any ideas? I think the issue is around the 2 single records at the start, and then the repeating data after.

```
ERROR Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Here is what I am calling

```
public async Task<List<ModelPageLocationList>> RefreshPageLocationListAsync ()
    {
        DataPageLocationList = new List<ModelPageLocationList>();

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(WebServiceSettings.WebServiceUrl, string.Empty));

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}", content.ToString());

                DataPageLocationList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelPageLocationList>>(content);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return (DataPageLocationList); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: It's the first line of the post

Answer (score 2):

Two things. Use `JsonProperty` to handle the `odata.metadata` property as the dot (`.`) in the property name will cause syntax problems.

```
public class ModelPageLocationList {
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}
```

Next based on the provided JSON example data you need to refactor the calling code

```
public async Task<ModelPageLocationList> RefreshPageLocationListAsync () {
    try {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(WebServiceSettings.WebServiceUrl, string.Empty));
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelPageLocationList>();
            return result;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: I don't have Content.ReadAsAsync as an option.

Comment: It is an extension method found in `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`

Comment: so no JsonConvert in your solution?

Comment: @DarrellUK It uses JsonConvert under the covers as a dependency

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize to your root object `ModelPageLocationList`, NOT a list of your root objects. Your JSON is an object not an array of objects. This will fix it:

```
DataPageLocationList = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelPageLocationList>(content);
```

Comment: I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'App.ModelPageLocationList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<App.ModelPageLocationList>'

Comment: @DarrellUK: Yeah that was just you using the wrong type for your variable in C#, `DataPageLocationList ` is *a* `ModelPageLocationList` not a list of `ModelPageLocationList`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the JSON Data you are trying to pass in, I can only provide two possible answers based on the information you have provided.

1) Make sure your JSON Looks like this:

```
{
    "odatametadata": "SomeDataHere",
    "value": [{
            "code": "Code1",
            "name": "Name1",
            "xTag": "XTag1"
        }, {
            "code": "Code1",
            "name": "Name1",
            "xTag": "XTag1"
        }, {
            "code": "Code1",
            "name": "Name1",
            "xTag": "XTag1"
        },
    ]
}
```

2 Add this attribute to your C# Class Model

```
public class ModelPageLocationList
{
    [JsonProperty("odatametadata")]
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("xTag")]
    public string XTag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: (it's the first line of the post, and I have no control over the data received).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get my code to work with the JSON data at the start of my post. Not ideal, and I would prefer to be able to do this without having to edit the JSON string.

```
public async Task<List<ModelPageLocationList>> RefreshPageLocationListAsync ()
    {
        DataPageLocationList = new List<ModelPageLocationList>();
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(WebServiceSettings.WebServiceUrl, string.Empty));

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE {0}", content.ToString());

                content = content.Substring(content.IndexOf('['), content.IndexOf(']') - content.IndexOf('[') + 1);
                Debug.WriteLine("AFTER {0}", content.ToString());

                DataPageLocationList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelPageLocationList>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return (DataPageLocationList);
    }
```

and the class from the JSON data

```
public class ModelPageLocationList
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks everyone for their replies.